# How to properly get id and tags name and value from json data using php

Tags: php

when I print that json data, I have the json content below

```
Arweave\SDK\Support\Transaction Object ( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 101 [last_tx] => tx101 
[owner] => tonyjohn [tags] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => loco1 [value] => loco1_value )
 [1] => Array ( [name] => loco2 [value] => loco2_tx_value ) ) [target] => 101 
[quantity] => 10 [data] => product101 [reward] => 20532973 [end] => test_end ) )
```

Now when I tried to get value of **id** and tags **name** with its corresponding **values**

It throws error

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**here is the code**

```
$file = 'product.json'
$data =file_get_contents($file);
print_r($data);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

// get id value
echo  $id = $json['id'];

// loop and get tags name and values
foreach($json as $tags){
$tag_name = $tags['tags']['name'];
$tag_value =$tags['tags']['value'];

}
```

Comment: The first error implies `file_get_contents` didn't return a string, therefore it must have failed. It probably can't find 'product.json'. Try `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $file);` if it's in the same folder as your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. * file_get_contents * is working fine. when I do `print_r($data);`. it dumps the json files i posted above. those error only occur when I tried to get the id value and tags name and values as per the codes  below `$json = json_decode($data, true);

// get id value
echo  $id = $json['id'];

// loop and get tags name and values
foreach($json as $tags){
$tag_name = $tags['tags']['name'];
$tag_value =$tags['tags']['value'];

}`

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If `file_get_contents` worked, then it returned a string, therefore the first error you're getting isn't logical. What does `echo gettype($data)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use object like array. Print $json variable and you will see object. If you want get access to id try it:

```
echo $json->attributes['id'];
```

Same situation with foreach.

```
foreach($json->attributes['tags'] as $tag){}
```

Comment: He's using `json_decode` with the `assoc` flag to true so it should return an array. Anyway, `json_encode` itself fails according to the errors he reports.

Comment: Yes, i didn't see that. Ok, he can try without assoc flag)